# How To Add Static Image to Table

Tags: html, css

I want to show a static image top-right side of my table. When i try to add css code like this it fails:

```
<style>
    .hoverTable{background:url(../../Images/taxi.jpg) top right no-repeat;
            background-attachment:fixed; }
</style>
```

But this works:

```
<style>
    body {background:url(../../Images/taxi.jpg) top right no-repeat;
            background-attachment:fixed; }
</style>
```

My table is something like this:

```
 <table class="hoverTable">

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model.Question[i]
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answers[i].Answer, new { @style = "width:20px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center;" })

                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

So how can i add a picture like image which shown as below?

[image]

Comment: Please add link to JSFiddle :-)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ma14kouw/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```html
 .hoverTable{
    background:url(../../Images/taxi.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width:100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `width:100%` for your table.

```
 .hoverTable{
    background:url(../../Images/taxi.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed; 
    width:100%;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/604139j5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<img>` tag in `<td>` where you want the image.

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/604139j5/1/